# Haskell illegal pattern match

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have been told that this function declaration is illegal:

f3 1 (f2 x) y

I do understand why this illegal, I think it has something to do with the second argument (f2 x). Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: That's not a declaration. It's an expression fragment. What is the surrounding code? And what error do you get?

Comment: Its part of an exam question of an introductory course to haskell. The question is:                                                  For the following function definition left-hand sides (dening functions f1, f2, f3, f4
and f5) using patterns, state if the patterns are illegal or not, if legal, explain precisely
what argument values they match, if illegal, explain why they are not allowed.                                                          (i) f1 1 (f2 x) y (ii) f2 0 (x:'x':cs) 8 (iii) f3 z y
(iv) f4 (a:[b]) (v) f5 a 1 [4,a] []

Comment: I understand them all except part (i)

Comment: As I said in my answer, `f2 x` is not a pattern. Syntactically, it's a function application. But in the argument positions of a function definition, only patterns are allowed.

Answer (score 8):

In a function definition, the parameters of the function must be [patterns](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-590003.17.1), that is, they must be

- a wildcard `_`, which matches everything and binds nothing,
- a variable pattern `var`, which matches everything and binds the corresponding argument to the parameter,
- a literal (integer, floating point, character or string), which matches arguments equal to the pattern,
- a value constructor applied to as many patterns as its arity demands (so patterns can be nested),
- a list pattern `[elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4]`,
- a labelled pattern `Con{ field1 = value1, field2 = value2 }`,
- a parenthesised pattern `(pattern)`,
- a tuple pattern `(pattern1, pattern2, pattern3)`,
- an *as-pattern*, `var@pattern`, binding the entire argument to `var` and components to the corresponding parts of the `pattern` if it matches, or
- an irrefutable pattern `~pattern`, which binds the argument resp. its parts to `pattern` resp. its parts, and causes a runtime error if the argument doesn't actually match `pattern`.

The part `(f2 x)` in the fragment

```
f3 1 (f2 x) y
```

is not a pattern, but an expression, a function (`f2`) applied to a value (`x`), therefore a function definition cannot have the form

```
f3 1 (f2 x) y = whatever
```

The closest legal function definition would be

```
f3 1 (F2 x) y = ...
```

with a (unary) *value constructor* `F2`.